# Bootstrap 4 Modal Moving page to left

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

When I open the Boostrap 4 Modal on my page, it shifts the page contents to the left slightly. I have managed to prevent this from happening to most of the content by adding a css class to the body when the modal is opened. However, for some reason this is not working for my nav's contents and they are being shifted to the left still when the modal is open. How can I fix this? Any help would be great, thanks.

HTML

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="navFixed">
    <div class="container-fluid container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="navigateToPage()">
            MyNav
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="navigateToPage()" title="Home">Home</a>
                </li>
                ...
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

...
</body>
```

JS

```
$('#demoModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('body, nav > .container').addClass('test');
})
```

CSS

```
.test[style] {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  color: red;
}

.test.modal-open {
  overflow: auto !important;
}

body.modal-open {
  margin-right: 0px
}
```

Comment: Normally this happens when the height of the page grows and the vertical scrollbar is displayed. The scrollbar causes the center of the page to be recalculated and the content appears to move left slightly.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to find the cause of this kind of errors what i do is remove all the page CSS (commenting it or renaming the css file and creating a blank one) then start uncommenting / adding css rules by blocks or by importance (for instance the first one you may want to add is the boostrap css file) and test and repeat until i find the culprit

My second aproach is to do the opposite, create a blank page and start adding the code (html, css, javascript) from the most important to the least important (first jquery then boostrap, the bootstrap blank page html, modal example...)

Same with the javascript, because sometimes javascript also changes CSS, specially if you have javascript plugins